# HTTP Proxy Support in Google API Client Library for C++

Tags: c++, http, c++11, proxy, google-api

Does Google API Client Library for C++ have support for HTTP Proxy? The use case examples for sending HTTP POST request at http://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/guide/making_http_requests.html do not mention anything about HTTP Proxy Support. Does it have dependencies on external libraries like libcurl or libjingle for HTTP Proxy?

Thanks